# Communication of intelligent agents

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a MAS of 4 agents, the first one has a path to the directory that it should send to everyone else. The problem is that they can't accept it.
Sender:

```
def send_path_to_agents(self):
    if self.path:
        parser_content = KQMLList.from_string(f'(path "{str(self.path)}")')
        parser_performative = KQMLPerformative('tell')
        parser_performative.set('content', parser_content)
        self.server.receive_request(None, parser_performative)
```

Receiver:

```
def receive_request(self, msg, content):
    logging.info(f"Received message: {msg}")
    logging.info(f"Content: {content}")

    if isinstance(content.head(), str) and content.head().startswith('path'):
        path = content.get(0).to_string()
        self.parse_directory(path)
    else:
        reply_content = KQMLList()
        reply_content.append('FAILURE')
        reply_content.append(':reason')
        reply_content.append('Invalid request')
        reply_msg = KQMLPerformative('reply')
        reply_msg.set('content', reply_content)
        self.server.reply(None, reply_msg)
        logging.warning("Invalid request received.")
```

Help me, I may be incorrectly prescribing getting the path